# show/hide div inside a show/hide div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, show-hide

I am making a blog sort of website, and when you click on the article header it expands (this works fine). At the bottom of this there is a comment button that expands the comments, im using the same code to do this but its not working. Im new to JQuery so any help would be much appreciated.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showArticle').hide();
    $('.articleTitle').show();
    $('.showComments').hide();
    $('.commentTitle').show();
    $('.articleTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.showArticle').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.commentTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.showComments').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
print "
<a href='#' class='articleTitle'>Article name[+]</a>
<div class='showArticle'>
Article about some stuff
<br>
<a href='#' class='commentTitle'>comments[+]</a>
<div class='showComments'>
Comments go here 
</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
";
}
```

FULL CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
session_start();

print " 
<html>
<head>
<title>Blog</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'>   
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.showArticle').hide();
$('.articleTitle').show();

$('.showComments').hide();
$('.commentTitle').show();

$('.articleTitle').click(function(){
$(this).next('.showArticle').slideToggle();
});



$('.commentTitle').click(function(){
$(this).next('.showComments').slideToggle();

});
});

</script>
</head>



<body>      

<header id='header'>
<div class='innertube'>
<h1>Time to blog </h1>

";

if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
print "You are not signed in";
}
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
print "<p>you are signed in as " . ($_SESSION['name']) . "<p>";
}

print "     
</div>
</header>
";



print "
<!--MAIN BODY-->
<div id='wrapper'>  
<main>
<div id='content'>
<div class='innertube'>
";

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
print "
<a href='#' class='articleTitle'>Article name</a>
<div class='showArticle'>
Article about some stuff
<br>
<a href='#' class='commentTitle'>comments[+]</a>
<div class='showComments'>
Comment
</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
";
}


print "     
</div>
</div>
</main>
";  



print "
<nav id='nav'>
<div class='innertube'>
<h3>Pages</h3>

";          
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
print" <ul>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Sign in</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 5</a></li>
</ul>";
}
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
print " <ul>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Sign out</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href=''>Link 5</a></li>
</ul> ";
}


</div>
</nav>
</div>



<footer id='footer'>
<div class='innertube'>
<p>Created by JReilly@14412625</p>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
";
?>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6cpfmejy/1/ ?

Comment: Works fine for me? https://jsfiddle.net/qejz28pj/ 1 Reason it may not work is because you print your HTML try doing it without the `for` loop

Comment: @theblackgigant loop shouldn't be the problem here at all..

Josh, try to provide more code.. this one you give us should work as you describe it.

Comment: It's work for me with the loop

Comment: The loop is need as this will be  generate through a database

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

**HTML**

**-----------------**

```
<a href='#' class='articleTitle'>Article name[+]</a>
<div class='showArticle' style="display:none;">
    Article about some stuff
    <br>
    <a href='#' class='commentTitle'>comments[+]</a>
    <div class='showComments' style="display:none;">
        Comments go here 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

**-----------------**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.articleTitle').click(function(){
        $('.showArticle').fadeToggle(200);
    });

    $('.commentTitle').click(function(){
        $('.showComments').fadeToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem u r facing with this ?

Comment: The article opens on click but the comments are already shown and clicking on the link ("comment title") it does nothing

Comment: Thank you but still not working, is it to do with print? or the loop?

Comment: loop doesn't required, print must be fine... I'm not aware of PHP.

Comment: i will do more research, thank for all the help so far

Comment: ok, a reboot was all it needed, not sure why but happy to see it working